# How can I use ScrollTo in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm quite new to React Native, I'm developing an app for advertising where there are categories and adverts listings. I would like to have the animation when the user clicks on a category, the screen should scroll downwards to the section with "Latest Ads". I'm not using ScrollView, I have used two Flatlists one for the categories and the other for products/adverts.

I have tried to use `scrollTo()` as shown in react native documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto)
Please help.

Below is part of my code in my JSX file that gives me an error:

```
//Scroller code starts
  const myScroller = () => {
    scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 90, animated: true });
  };
  // Scroller code ends
  const handleSelectCategory = (item) => {
    setSearchData((prevSearchData) => {
      return { ...prevSearchData, categories: item.term_id, page: 1 };
    });
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_CAT_NAME",
      cat_name: [item.name],
    });
    setLoading(true);
    myScroller();   
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **ref** to scroll

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
...

...
const scrollRef = useRef(null); // inside your function component
...

const myScroller = () => {
    scrollRef ?.current ?.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 90, animated: true });
};

...
<FlatList
  ref={scrollRef} // put reference in FlatList which need to scroll
...
```